# Using gtools::mixedsort or alternatives with dplyr::arrange

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to order a dataframe by making use of `dplyr::arrange`. The issue is that the column I am trying to sort on contains both a fixed string followed by a number, as for instance generated by the dummycode below.

```
  dummydf<-data.frame(values=rnorm(100),sortcol=paste0("ABC",sample(1:100,100,replace=FALSE)))
```

By default, using `dummydf %>% arrange(sortcol)` would generate a df which is sorted alphanumerically (?) but this is of course not the desired result:

```
values sortcol
0.708081720    ABC1
0.041348322   ABC10
1.730962886  ABC100
0.423480861   ABC11
-1.545837266   ABC12
-1.345539947   ABC13
-0.078998792   ABC14
0.088712174   ABC15
0.670583024   ABC16
1.238837680   ABC17
-1.459044293   ABC18
-2.028535223   ABC19
0.779514385    ABC2
1.360509910   ABC20
```

In this example, I would like to sort the column as `gtools::mixedsort` would do, making sure ABC2 follows ABC1 and is not preceed by ABC1-19 and ABC100 `mixedsort(as.character(dummydf$sortcol))` would do that trick.

Now, I am aware I could do this by using `sub` in my `arrange` argument: `dummydf %>% arrange(as.numeric(sub("ABC","",sortcol)))` but that is mainly because my string is something fixed (although any regex could be used to capture the last digits following any string I suppose).

I am just wondering: is there a more "elegant" and generic way to get this done with `dplyr::arrange`, in the same fashion as `gtools::mixedsort`?

Kind regards,

FM

Comment: One slightly different approach you might consider is splitting the sortcol into two columns, for example with tidyr: `extract(dummydf, sortcol, c("sort1", "sort2"), "([A-Z]+)(\\d+)", convert = TRUE) %>% arrange(sort1, sort2)`

Comment: Just to clarify, would you be against a `data.table` answer?

Comment: @AkhilNair not necessarily, I would just like an elegant and generic function that does the trick.

Comment: @docendodiscimus thanks, that is an interesting way of making the function more generic! However: is there a way to make it  bit more 'robust' (e.g. to deal with special characters in the column such as ABC_1 or to deal with numbers inside the column such as A1B2C3)?

Comment: What's the problem with using `gtools::mixedsort`?

Comment: @Arun, I would like to use it as an "arrange option" of the `dplyr::arrange` function for reasons of convenience. I am aware I can just call it directly to sort the column of a data.table (like in the answer of @Akhil Nair) though this is really a question on how to create nice elegant and legible code.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a functional solution making use of the [mysterious](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3662542/why-does-the-ordering-function-invert-itself) identity `order(order(x)) == rank(x)`.

```
mixedrank = function(x) order(gtools::mixedorder(x))
dummydf %>% dplyr::arrange(mixedrank(sortcol))
```

Comment: This is so elegant because it still allows to further `arrange` by the other variables. Kind of unexpected that this function is not part of gtools. You could of course simplify it to `dplyr::arrange(order(gtools::mixedorder( sortcol )))`

Answer (score 8):

I don't see this answer posted so I'll throw it out. You can use mixedorder with slice to arrange it.

```
dummydf %>% 
  slice(mixedorder(sortcol))
```

Comment: Nice (concise).

Answer (score 5):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dummydf = data.table(dummydf)
dummydf[gtools::mixedorder(as.character(sortcol))]
```

Honestly just copied your example and stuck it in as the select argument in the `data.table` syntax. You already did all the hard work :).

Comment: I like the answer. Although I would prefer dplyr, for reasons of code "legibility" and use of the margrittr "piping" (i.e. the `%>%` operator) which is how I build up most of my data wrangling code, I think this is an excelent and elegant alternative. For now, I'll upvote it but if no one can come with a dplyr alternative I'll accept it asap.

Comment: No, I agree, that's why I wanted to clarify first in the comments. I did prefer `dplyr` before I got to grips with `data.table` syntax, but I find the versatility of `data.table` to be invaluable now compared.

Comment: @AkhilNair May I ask why it works? I failed to understand the syntax. I could see that "sortcol" get sorted, but how does data.table know which column to look after? I didn't know similar usage in the tutorial but I likely miss it. Many thanks!

Comment: Running `gtools::mixedorder(as.character(dummydf$sortcol))` normally returns a vector of indexes - e.g., `c(79, 27, 93, ...`. In the `data.table` context, the rows are then arranged by the index vector. For example, with a `data.table` called `dt` of 3 rows, if you say `dt[c(3, 1, 2)]`, it will show the 2nd row first, 3rd row second, and 1st row third.

Comment: @AkhilNair Thanks! I have got confused with mixedsort! Now everything is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to Akhil Nair for his `data.table` answer which is what the first code snippet derives from.  If you like the `data.table` answer but still want `magrittr` piping, you can consider calculating a new column and using piping with `data.table` to get your output:

```
dummydf %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(row_lookup = gtools::mixedorder(as.character(sortcol))) %>%
  data.table::data.table() %>% 
  .[.$row_lookup]
```

I think it's debatable whether that helps or detracts from the readability.

If you don't want to call `data.table`, you can go through some extra contortions to calculate a column you can use `dplyr::arrange` on.  Here's one example:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_cols(dummydf,
          dummydf %>% 
            tibble::rowid_to_column("order") %>% 
            mutate(rowname = gtools::mixedorder(as.character(sortcol))) %>% 
            arrange(rowname) %>% 
            select(order)) %>% 
arrange(order)
```

I think this code is more confusing to read and isn't worth those extra contortions to avoid `data.table`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that will allow for sorting if there are repeats and multiple conditions to sort. Most previous answers are not generic: they freeze the ordering at level 1.

```
df <- data.frame(values = rnorm(100),
                 sortcol1 = paste0("ASORT", sample(1:100, 100, replace = TRUE)),
                 sortcol2 = paste0("BSORT", sample(1:100, 100, replace = TRUE)),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

df %>%
mutate(
    `sortcol1` = factor(`sortcol1`, ordered = T, levels = unique(gtools::mixedsort(`sortcol1`))),
    `sortcol2` = factor(`sortcol2`, ordered = T, levels = unique(gtools::mixedsort(`sortcol2`)))
) %>%
arrange(`sortcol1`, `sortcol2`)
```