# ranking dataframe using two columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, ranking, multiple-conditions

I am new to using R, and I am having hard time trying to rank dataframe using two columns in R.
The data is in the form of this.

```
A B
1 1
2 1
2 1
4 4
5 3
```

I want result to be in the form of

```
A B Rank
1 1 1
2 1 2
2 1 2
4 4 5
5 3 4
```

which is ranked by B first, and the A is used to rank if there is equal value in B.
I think my question is very similar to
[How to rank rows by two columns at once in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27260310/how-to-rank-rows-by-two-columns-at-once-in-r)
and I tried the answers for this, but this didn't work for me.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you explain exactly how you obtained your rank column? Also, why is the third row different in the two data sets?

Comment: I think there are some typos in the second example table. Column `A` used to have a 3 in it (replaced with a 2) and column `B` used to have a 2 in it (replaced by a 1).

Comment: For a broader description of different ties methods see [How to emulate SQLs rank functions in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446254/how-to-emulate-sqls-rank-functions-in-r). There you also find a nice [description of `data.table::frank`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28141041) (highly relevant for you, when ranking on several columns).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `data.table::frank` or `dplyr::min_rank`:

#### `data.table::frank`

```r
dt$Rank <- frank(dt, B, A, ties.method = "min")
dt
  A B Rank
1 1 1    1
2 2 1    2
3 2 1    2
4 4 4    5
5 5 3    4
```

#### `dplyr::min_rank`

```
mutate(dt, Rank = min_rank(paste(B,A)))
  A B Rank
1 1 1    1
2 2 1    2
3 2 1    2
4 4 4    5
5 5 3    4
```

Data

```
dt <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,2,4,5), B = c(1,1,1,4,3))
```

Comment: I was not aware of frank either, to do it on reference this seems to be the way `dt[, Rank := frank(.SD, ties.method = "min"), .SDcols = c("B", "A")]`

Comment: Is it right that in the `dplyr` solution, `paste` won't work correctly if some of the values of `A` and `B` are two digits?

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is sort on B and A, give it a group ID and then rank on this group ID

**Data**

```
dt <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L), B = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
3L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.frame"
))
```

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)

setorder(dt, B, A)
dt[, Rank := .GRP, by = .(A, B)][, Rank := rank(Rank, ties.method = "min")]

dt
   A B Rank
1: 1 1    1
2: 2 1    2
3: 2 1    2
4: 5 3    4
5: 4 4    5
```

**dyplr**

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>% 
  arrange(B, A) %>%
  group_by(B, A) %>%
  mutate(Rank = cur_group_id()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Rank = rank(Rank, ties.method = "min"))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
      A     B  Rank
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     1
2     2     1     2
3     2     1     2
4     5     3     4
5     4     4     5
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this base R option could help

```
transform(
  df,
  Rank = rank(A[order(B, A)], ties.method = "min")
)
```

which gives

```
  A B Rank
1 1 1    1
2 2 1    2
3 2 1    2
4 4 4    5
5 5 3    4
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is using a function called `arrange` from dplyr to order first by B, then A, create the rank as the order of the columns, then re-arrange with the original arrangement to simulate your output.

To repeat the rank of identical entries, we can add that `ifelse` statement that looks at the previous row and keeps the rank if this row has identical A and B values.

Here's how that would look like:

```r
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,2,4,5),
                 B = c(1,1,1,4,3))

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    arrange(B,A) %>%
    mutate(Rank = 1:n(),
           Rank = ifelse(A == lag(A, default = 0) & B == lag(B, default = 0), 
                         lag(Rank), Rank)) %>%
    arrange(A,B)
#>   A B Rank
#> 1 1 1    1
#> 2 2 1    2
#> 3 2 1    2
#> 4 4 4    5
#> 5 5 3    4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: But the OP is getting duplicated 2 rank. And your code gives a different result

Comment: Ah yeah, I didn't notice. I'll edit a patch